# Selecting and Binding Date AND Time in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

This seems like it should be easy, but I haven't found an easy solution.  I understand that I can have a CalendarDatePicker, DatePicker, etc, or I can have a TimePicker.  I could place both on my page and bind to two separate properties, which themselves notify a DateTime property I care about which takes the Date (year, day, month) from the first picker, and the time from the second picker.
*emphasized text*
But that seems totally hackish.  Is there a way to bind to a single DateTime object while picking a Date AND Time?  I.E. I really just want to combine a DatePicker/CalendarDatePicker and a TimePicker into one logical XAML control that binds to a single DateTime object.

Comment: What stops you from creating a usercontrol that contains both and expose a single `DateTime` dependency property?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this simple function i wrote to combine your date and time. It functions by removing the default time in your DatePicker and adding the time from TimePicker to that variable.

```
private static DateTime CombineDateAndTime(DateTime dateObj,DateTime timeObj)
    {
        DateTime newDateTime;

        //get timespan from the date object
        TimeSpan spanInDate = dateObj.TimeOfDay;

        //subtract it to set date objects time to 0:00
        dateObj = dateObj.Subtract(spanInDate);

        //now add your newTime to date object
        newDateTime = dateObj.Add(timeObj.TimeOfDay);

        //return new value
        return newDateTime;
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
// code behind
DateTime date;
TimeSpan time
{
  get => date.TimeOfDay;
  set
  {
    date = date.AddTicks(value.Ticks);
  }
}

// xaml
<DatePicker Date={x:Bind date, Converter={StaticResource DateTimeToOffsetConverter}}" 
/>
<TimePicker Time={X:Bind time}" />
```

Answer (score -1):

I have found the following code helpful:-

```
    int rex01=  t21.Date.Value.Year;                      
    int rex02 = t21.Date.Value.Month;        
    int rex03 = t21.Date.Value.Day;            
    int rex04 = t22.Time.Hours;           
    int rex05 = t22.Time.Minutes;        
    int rex06 = t22.Time.Seconds;  

    DateTime T02 = new DateTime(rex01, rex02, rex03, rex04, rex05, rex06);
```

Please note t21 is a DatePicker and t22 is a TimePicker. 
Currently used with respect to SQLite and UWP.

Comment: As I said in my original question, I understand you can use a time and date picker separately.